# Passing generator expression to all()

Tags: python, iterable, generator-expression

The built-in function [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) is supposed to be equivalent to:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

But when a generator expression is passed to `all()`, the behaviors are different:

```
l=(1,2,3)
def all2(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
print all(e > 0 for e in l) # <generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000096AB510>
print all2(e > 0 for e in l) # True
```

Same goes for the other similar built-ins. Is there a simple way to fix it? (Converting the generator expression to a tuple or a list is not really an option, because of the footprint.)

Comment: Your first example works just fine for me in 2.7.6 - what version are you using?

Comment: Make sure you're using the builtin `all()`, and not some function of your own named `all`.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you sure you didn't name a function `all` or forget to write `all` before the genexp or something?

Comment: Did you happen to write `from numpy import *` at the top of your script? `numpy` has a `numpy.all` function that doesn't work like the built-in `all`. This is one of the reasons not to use `import *`.

Comment: How I can accept an answer in a comment? I believe user2357112 has already answered my question. I didn't `import *`, but I was using WinPython which might have imported that for me. Thanks.

Comment: restart your Python interactive shell -- you have renamed `all` to something else i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` has its own `all` function that behaves differently from the built-in `all`:

```
>>> numpy.all(x for x in range(3))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000001FD2900>
>>> all(x for x in range(3))
False
```

If for some reason `all` refers to `numpy.all` instead of `__builtin__.all`, perhaps due to a `from numpy import *` or due to automatic imports performed by the Python distribution you're using, you will get the NumPy behavior instead of what the built-in does.